# UNIX file permissions issue

Tags: unix

I am trying to enable https/SSL to secure our applications running on jboss eap 6 server. 
I created a keystore.jks file with full read/write permissions and mentioned the location of this keystore in the standalone.xml

But the server log says it can’t find that file. 
I guess it is related to some file permissions issue. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks
Aadil

Comment: yes the keystore.jks has maximum permissions. 
i created the file using root user, changed ownership to userA and chmod 777. 
trying to run the server under userA. 
The jboss server is not able to find the file.

Comment: Do you use a relative or absolute path ?

Comment: did you bounce the server? Good luck.

Comment: bounced both the aws instance and jboss server several times